# Shifting and adding a std_logic_vector (has 36 but must have 18 elements)

Tags: vhdl, fpga, intel-fpga, quartus

I'm facing some weird errors from quartus when I try this.

Here's the code (all the unsigned & other weird functions was my attempt at persuading Quartus to compile it.)

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

...
variable data : std_logic_vector(17 downto 0) := "000000000000000011";

...

-- 00000000111111000 original
-- 00000000000011111 shifted
-- 00000000000011000 result (AND)

data := std_logic_vector(unsigned(data) & shift_right(unsigned(data), 4));


-- 00000000011111000 original
-- 00000000111110000 shifted
-- 00000000111111000 result (OR)

data := std_logic_vector(unsigned(data) or shift_left(unsigned(data), 1));
```

I've left out quite a lot of the code, but the broken parts are left the same.

I'm getting

> Error (10344): VHDL expression error at snake_driver.vhd(66): expression has 36 elements, but must have 18 elements

How to do it right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `&` operator is not the same as the `and` operator in VHDL. You are looking for the `and` operator to perform a bitwise and operation. `&` is the concatenation operator on vectors and using it between two 18-bit vectors will produce a 36-bit vector (and likewise a vector width mismatch) as indicated by your error message.

Comment: Oh that's silly. Okay, this fixed it. And, am I doing it right? I'm not really sure about all the type casting. Is this the easiest method?

Comment: If you're trying to shift or rotate by a constant value, it is often easier to slice and concatenate a std_logic_vector. A simple shift right by 4 would be `data := x"0"&data(17 downto 4);`. A rotate right by 4 would be `data := data(3 downto 0) & data(17 downto 4);`

Comment: Alternatively, you could just use `unsigned` as your data type for `data`. You can pretty much treat it just like a std_logic_vector.

Comment: +1 for "Alternatively, you could just use unsigned". Any time you are throwing typecasts at a problem, stop and ask if you're fighting the type system instead of using it. Usually they are pointing you at a better design. (but not always!)